# Role claim is ignored by blazor webassembly client application

Tags: c#, .net, blazor-webassembly

I have 2 applications (.net 8 preview):

1. web api
2. wasm blazor client app

on webapi I set up roles, used it on controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UserProfilesController : BaseController
{
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllProfiles(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var query = new GetAllUserProfilesQuery();
            var response = await Mediator.Send(query, cancellationToken);
            var profiles = _mapper.Map<List<UserProfileResponse>>(response.Payload);
            return Ok(profiles);
        } 
}
```

and it works perfectly.

Now I want to restrict profiles page on razor component of the client application.

In the client's program.cs I have

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization(opt => opt.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "role");
```

but it doesn't work. I output it like

```
@page "/userprofiles"
@*@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] commented out because it doesn't work*@
<h3>UserProfileList</h3>
@inject HttpClient httpClient;
@inject IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory
    @if (user is not null)
    {
        <h3>@user.Identity.Name</h3>
        <div class="m-2 p-2">
            Is Authenticated: @user.Identity.IsAuthenticated
        </div>
        <div class="m-2 p-2">
            Authentication Type: @user.Identity.AuthenticationType
        </div>
        <div class="m-2 p-2">
            Admin Role: @user.IsInRole("Admin")
        </div>
        <div class="m-2 p-2">
            <h5>Claims</h5>
            @foreach (var claim in user.Claims)
            {
                <span>
                    @claim.Type
                </span>
                <span>:</span>
                <span>
                    @claim.Value
                </span>
                <br />
            }
        </div>
    }
```

the output is

```
Is Authenticated: True
Authentication Type: jwt
Admin Role: False
Claims
sub : admin@example.com
jti : b35dd0c2-e1a5-4f6a-8f47-360f7f6b3edb
email : admin@example.com
IdentityId : 27f90072-8347-4d8f-8c7b-122982b04ad7
UserProfileId : 265ca74a-d36d-48bb-ac32-08db593ac40f
role : Admin
nbf : 1684685344
exp : 1684692544
iat : 1684685344
iss : MyIss
aud : SwaggerUI
```

Althouh it is clear that there's role claim with 'Admin' value, the user appears to be not in Admin role

Comment: Hi,
Is it resolved ?

Comment: @User1162527 yes, look here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/40314